# how to make SlidingDrawer transparent

Tags: android, gridview, slidingdrawer

Im currently trying to add the `SlidingDrawer` in my application..
My activity consists `GridView` and the `SlidingDrawer` will be coming from bottom to top..
Now my problem is i need to make the `SlidingDrawer` as transparent and also move my `GridView` 
to top to some extent.. Is this possible to make.. Im new to android.. help me out with this...

If moving the `GridView` is not an good idea then i want the `SlidingDrawer` to come above the `GridView` and make it as a transparent so tat my `GridView` is visible

Thanks...

Comment: Additionally im having 5 `TextView` and `RelativeLayout` in the `SlidingDrawer`..  The `RelativeLayout` consists of `EditText` and a `Button` in it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make the `SlidingDrawer` transparent, set its `android:background` attribute to `@null`. See the following example;

```
<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" android:content="@+id/content"
        android:background="@null">
...
...

</SlidingDrawer>
```

**Update:**

Above code will make the whole drawer transparent. To make the only the content part, transparent, you can do something like this;

```
<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:handle="@+id/handle" android:content="@+id/content"
        android:background="#eeffae" >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/handle" android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp" android:src="@drawable/handle" />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@null">

...
...
</LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Thanks mudassir... Its working now.. I have another doubt tat can i make the `SlidingDrawer` to slide for half screen of my activity..

Comment: Sorry buddy, I didn't find anything about that yet. But see the updated answer above, may be that is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks mudassir.. It will help me a lot... and thanks for ur up vote :)